# Enumeration printing wrong name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, enumeration

I've got an enum of body joints

```
public enum anchorName
{
    HEAD_NECK = 1,

    TORSO_NECK = 1,
    TORSO_LSHOULDER = 2,
    ...
    TORSO_GUT = 8,

    THORAX_GUT = 1,
    ... and so on
}
```

The below adds a head to the neck joint of the torso

```
// Code to add a limb 
// addLimb(TYPE, OutgoingJoint, ParttoConnectTo, JointtoConnectTo)
addLimb(BodyPart.Type.HEAD, BodyPart.anchorName.HEAD_NECK, torso, BodyPart.anchorName.TORSO_NECK)
```

The new `BodyPart.Type.HEAD` created stores its connections in an array

```
public class Part
{
    public anchorName anchor[];
    public Part part[];
}

public Part addLimb(BodyPart.Type type, BodyPart.anchorName inLocalAnchor, BodyPart.Part destinationPart, BodyPart.anchorName jointName)
{
    anchor[inLocalAnchor] = jointName;
    part[inLocalAnchor] = destinationPart;
}
```

Now, when I call

```
foreach(BodyPart.Part part in list)
{
    foreach(BodyPart.anchorName anchorname in part.anchor)
    {
        Debug.Log(anchorname);
    }
}
```

I get the incorrect enum name but the value is still a correct one. ie. `HEAD_NECK` becoming `THORAX_GUT`

I tried this `Debug.Log(anchorName.HEAD_NECK);` and it instantly spits out `TORSO_NECK`

Is there some way I can preserve the correct name? Functionally it works, but its a nightmare for debug purposes and in the future when I have many actors it would be unfeasible to try and work out which ones are correct and what isn't.

Comment: Hi @Natharantos, `HEAD_NECK` and `TORSO_NECK` are sharing same value, please revise is this typo or any reason to implement this? Thank you.

Comment: If that is really your enum and you need both values to have the same value `1` then you would rather use `Debug.Log(nameof(anchorName.HEAD_NECK));`

Comment: @YongShun it wouldn't be producing an error if they were different numbers. The above is correct
@derHugo This solves the issue at this level, but I want to be able to save the ``anchorName`` as it is typed, in a variable. When I use the enum it gets converted into the last enum declared of the same int value. I thought the name was preserved and I would be able to call it back up

Comment: Enums variables/fields literally hold the numeric value. If you have multiple names assigned the same value, there's no way to determine which name was used to produce that value. And `jointName = (anchorName)1` is valid code, no "name" is ever used.